# Mailto links affecting code with no <a href tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have wracked my brain and can not find the reason this is happening. I have some links in one div that are mailto which work fine. But P tags and an image in a div in the next column seem to be inheriting the mailto.

I am using bootstrap. Has anyone come across this before? Can anyone see something I am missing?

Top of container with affected code:

```
<div class="row rowSettings col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-left sidepanel">
```

Some divs, then this div with the mailto links:

```
                <li class="leftSubNavLinks"><a class="sublinks" href="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=message subject&body=prepopulated message" target="_blank"Contact</li>
```

and the following div that is inheriting the mailto:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 text-left"> 
     <div class="col-sm-8 titleContainer">
          <img src="url/image.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 titleContainer">
          <h1 class="mainTitle"> Title text</h1>
     </div>
</div>    
     <div class="col-sm-9 clearfix"> 
          <p class="bodyCopy" id="body-text">some text here</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: type error `target="_blank"Contact</li>` should be **`target="_blank">Contact</a></li>`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed your `<a>`

```
<li class="leftSubNavLinks">
  <a class="sublinks" href="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=message subject&body=prepopulated message" target="_blank">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Comment: What is the reason behind negative vote? Who so ever gave it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing your `<a>` tag

```
<li class="leftSubNavLinks">
    <a class="sublinks" href="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=message subject&body=prepopulated message" target="_blank"Contact
</li>
```

Should be:

```
<li class="leftSubNavLinks">
    <a class="sublinks" href="mailto:email@domain.com?subject=message subject&body=prepopulated message" target="_blank">Contact</a>
</li>
```

The browser will try to "fix" your broken code by closing the tag where it thinks it should be closed. This is almost certainly not where it *should* be closed which is why your following HTML is being bundled up into the `<a>`.